# IOS date conversion + timezone issue + returning always -1 day even after timezone.

Tags: ios, objective-c

I wrote function to convert date from string to date. The code is as below

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    [calendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];

    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
    [df setDateFormat:@"dd MMM, yyyy"];

    NSDateComponents *comp = [calendar components:NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit|NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:[df dateFromString:nDate]];
   [comp setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];

    NSLog(@"%@",[calendar dateFromComponents:comp]);
```

I am passing nDate as: 10 Feb,2014, but function is retiring me 2014-02-09 18:30:00 +0000. Let me know what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried setting the NSTimeZone of your date components as well?

Comment: Try setting calendar on data components object.

Comment: Use an `NSDateFormatter` for the output as well and `NSLog` that string.

Comment: Yes, I did that. I got the answer. Thank you for showing the interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `NSLog()` will just call `NSDate`'s `description` method. This will not set the timezone to what you expect when logging your date. You can try this instead:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [df stringFromDate:[calendar dateFromComponents:comp]]);
```